# How to prevent commits on a pull request?

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to avoid further push on a open pull request on GitHib.

I had recently the issue:

- received a PR
- pulled and testedit locally for approval
- someone pushed changes on the PR's branch (I had not visibility about this)
- I approved a pull request having different change  from what i've been testing

What's the best practice to avoid this un wanted behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: You can dismiss pull request reviews with new pushes. https://help.github.com/articles/enabling-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/

Answer (score 5):

You cannot restrict the ability of the submitter to add (or replace) commits to a PR. This is a critical feature, since it's the only way by which the committer can "edit" the pull request to fix issues, typos, etc. Without that, every single mistake would require closing a PR and opening a new one, which would quickly get frustrating for everyone involved.

If you're concerned about changes to a PR between the time you test it and the time you merge it, then rather than using github to merge the PR you can simply merge it (using `git merge`) locally once you have finished inspection and testing. This way you can be 100% certain that the code you're merging is the code you tested.

There are other review tools (like [gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/)] that make it much more obvious when someone has submitted modifications to a change request, but with Github you simply have to keep your eye on the commit ids.

Comment: IMHO there should be a locking feature, when someone is reviewing the PR. Preventing edits. If edits has to be made, you can then release the lock. Like this it's error prone. The solution to merge locally works... but then... we are going away from the PR. Because after that you should the push directly localmaster-> repo master

Comment: You might be interested in [pastamaker](https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2017/pastamaker).

Comment: is GitLab have same features @larsks?